# Mass Creation of Google Leaderboards

Tags: google-play-games

I have a game where there are about 68 objectives that all have their own time tracking, with more on the way. Is there a way to create leaderboards on Google Play en masse? Doing them all individually would be incredibly tedious and error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the publishing api: see https://developers.google.com/games/services/publishing/quickstart for all the details.